# Jquery .css('background', 'value'); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason the jQuery `.css("background",` is not working. Does anyone know how to make it work? I am trying the following code.

```
jQuery('.image').css('background', 'url("/image.jpg") no-repeat cover bottom');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid `background-position` should before `background-size` and place a `/` in-between.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background

> ```
> <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>
> ```

**CSS**

```
background: url(/image.jpg) bottom / cover no-repeat;
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery('.image').css('background', 'url(/image.jpg) bottom / cover no-repeat');
```

Answer (score 4):

This Is Work You Can See in below.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('.image').css('background', 'url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQTpEb2TLuGVF1Y72YDsvLC60_xgaZoMUrieRpkHoxUWMHf30o3) bottom / cover no-repeat');
});
```

```css
.image
{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```